# Transforming a tuple basis into a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U=sp\{(1,4,1),(1,16,13)  \}=sp\{u_1,u_2\}$. Find a condition (equation or a system of equations) on $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$ such that $(a,b,c)\in U$.
>
> In other words, show $U$ as a solution space of a homogeneous system.

If I do $(a,b,c)=xu_1+yu_2$ I get $a=x+y \\ b= 4x+16y \\ c = x+13y$

But I don't think this is the right way. In general, how can we transform a vector set into equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have

$a=x+y \\ b= 4x+16y \\ c = x+13y$

you can take linear combinations of the equations to eliminate $x$.

$c-a=12y \\ b-4a=12y$

Eliminating $y$ as well,

$c-a=b-4a\\ \Rightarrow 3a-b+c=0$

which is an equation satisfied by $(a,b,c)$.

Conversely, you can show that if $3a-b+c=0$ then there exist real $x,y$ such that

$a=x+y \\ b= 4x+16y \\ c = x+13y$

holds

Comment: What if $x$ or $y$ wouldn't cancel out?

Comment: You can always cancel them out. Try to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination Gauss-Jordan Elimination. It is the same problem as finding out solutions to the system of linear equations
$a=x+y \\ b= 4x+16y \\ c = x+13y$ for $x,y$. Once you solve fully (using Gauss-Jordan Elimination), you will understand when solutions exist and when they do not.

Comment: Ah we basically did RREF operation on a matrix here.